# Connecting my OctoPrint to a Google drive folder

Tags: octoprint, simplify3d, raspberry-pi

Is there a way where my upload folder on my OctoPrint server would be a folder on my Google drive so that I could save my G-code that was generated using Simplify3d to an existing folder on my desktop at which it would then automatically be uploaded into my RPi via the internet.

Or maybe a watched folder that can be accessed via internet?

Answer (score 3):

You could mount your google drive using gdrivefs on your pi following this tutorial: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=109587
However, I have to ask: why send the file to the internet? Is your printer/pi on a separate network than your desktop where you are slicing?

If they're on the same network, you'd be better off setting up a samba share on your raspberry pi (https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/samba-file-server/) and then mounting that directory from your desktop (https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-linux-samba-shares-from-windows-10/).

In either case, you could set the directory (the gdrive directory or the samba share) as the watched folder in octoprint's config.yaml (http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/configuration/config_yaml.html#folder).